# Wordpress schema json-ld won't show on search

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, schema, json-ld

I have this code added on function and the code is visible on the site, but my problem is it won't display on search, do I have any missing codes?

```
function site_schema_test(){
  ?>
  <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org/",
      "@type": "Product",
      "name": "Guns",
      "aggregateRating": {
      "@type": "AggregateRating",
      "ratingValue": "3.4",
      "ratingCount": "100"
    },
    "offers":
      {
        "@type": "AggregateOffer",
        "lowPrice": "100.99",
        "highPrice": "999.99",
        "priceCurrency": "PHP"
      }
    }
  </script>
  <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'site_schema_test' );
```

Comment: when do you have published the json-ld snippet? it could take much time before Google takes structured data into SERP.

Comment: With "search", you mean Google Search? And with "won’t show" you mean Google’s Product rich result?

Comment: Yes "search" means Google Search.